# How can I INSERT data in TEXT datatype field? (Informix)

Tags: sql, informix

```
 CREATE TABLE updater
 (
    nzp_up SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    version VARCHAR(50),
    status INT,
    report TEXT
 );

INSERT INTO updater (version, status,report) values ('TestVersion' , 0,"123123123");
```

-617 SQL error: A blob data type must be supplied within this context.

Comment: You can use the `LOAD` command.  Refer to my similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074364/informix-7-3-isql-insert-statement-text-blob-clob-field-insert-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `|` (pipe) delimited file, you can use the `LOAD` command to insert values into blob & text data types.  I had the same problem in the past - go to link in my comment

Answer (score 1):

See my question: [Consistent method of inserting TEXT column to Informix database using JDBC and ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483284/consistent-method-of-inserting-text-column-to-informix-database-using-jdbc-and-o)

It seems that some tools like ODBC drivers can insert text as `TEXT` while others like JDBC drivers must use PreparedStatent or other techniques.

Comment: Some drivers spot the relevant error message and then convert the SQL to use a placeholder in place of the string literal that does not work as BYTE or TEXT value, and convert the string literal into a blob structure (a loc_t structure).  Others don't - not unreasonably, since the parsing involved is contorted.  If you have support for Informix, please register a request with Tech Support.  It's been a problem for over 20 years now.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO updater (version, status,report) 
values ('TestVersion' , 0,"123123123");
```

and

```
INSERT INTO updater (version, status,report) 
values ('TestVersion' , 0,'123123123');
```

have the same effect in mySql.So lets try without double quotes in SQL.

Comment: I asked some of professionals and they told that it impossible without specific tools (like stream in C#)

Comment: Sadly, that does not work with Informix; it does not support a string literal representation for TEXT or BYTE values.