# Inserting data into TEXT type column in Informix

Tags: text, informix

How do I insert data into a columm with the type TEXT in Informix via SQL. If there are two other columns that I also want to insert/update - is the only way to save it in a file and LOAD it?

Or if I want to do do via SQL statements - can you give the syntax?

Comment: Which language are you using?  There are ways to do it in ESQL/C; I believe it can be done with JDBC too, and probably ODBC, and ... but what you can't do is use a simple string to hold the value.  In ESQL/C, you might use: `EXEC SQL INSERT INTO SomeTable(Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES(:host1, :host2, :host3);` but one of the host variables would need to be of the appropriate type for TEXT, namely a `loc_t` or locator structure.

Answer (score 0):

The load command works, and you can also use ESQL/C to do it (it is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074849/1385896) that you might already found).

About doing it in a simple insert,

You can use the VALUES clause to insert a value, but the only value that you can give that column is null. However, you can use the SELECT form of the INSERT statement to copy a TEXT or value from another table.

You can see here the docs for [Text data type](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ddi57.htm).

Answer (score 0):

See my question: [Consistent method of inserting TEXT column to Informix database using JDBC and ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483284/consistent-method-of-inserting-text-column-to-informix-database-using-jdbc-and-o)

It is easy with JDBC and PreparedStatement. ODBC works little different but is able to insert string with simple SQL `INSERT` (without preparing).