# How do I install an ODBC library in Jython

Tags: jdbc, odbc, jython

In python is possible to install pyodbc fairly easy, but in jython you are supposed either to install django, and to instal jdbc and then I do not know what else. Does any body know the proper steps? it is for windows an jython 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jython you can use JDBC drivers, and via JDBC-ODBC bridge you can connect to  ODBC configured source. With [`zxJDBC`](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html) module you can use JDBC database just like DB-API2 compliant Python database interface. Have a look at example of such usage with Informix database: [Consistent method of inserting TEXT column to Informix database using JDBC and ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483284/consistent-method-of-inserting-text-column-to-informix-database-using-jdbc-and-od)