# Error Inserting Entry With Text Column That Contains New Line And Quotes

Tags: sql, informix

I have an Informix 11.70 database.I am unable to sucessfully execute this insert statement on a table.

```
INSERT INTO some_table(
    col1,
    col2,
    text_col,
    col3) 
VALUES(
    5, 
    50, 
    CAST('"id","title1","title2"
"row1","some data","some other data"
"row2","some data","some other"' AS TEXT), 
    3);
```

The error I receive is:

> [Error Code: -9634, SQL State: IX000]  No cast from char to text.

I found that I should add this statement in order to allow using new lines in text literals, so I added this above the same query I have already written:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE('t');
```

Still, I receive the same error.

I have also read the IBM documentation that says: to alternatively allow new lines, I could set the `ALLOW_NEWLINE` parameter in the `ONCONFIG` file. I suppose the last one requires administrative access to the server to alter that config file, which I do not have, and I prefer not to take advantage of this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention an important detail in the question - I use Java and the Hibernate ORM to access my Informix database, thus some of the suggested approaches (the `loc_t` handling in particular) in [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482693/error-inserting-entry-with-text-column-that-contains-new-line-and-quotes/10483762#10483762) are unfortunately not applicable. Also, I need to store large data of dynamic length and I fear the `LVARCHAR` column would not be sufficient to hold it.

The way I got it working was to follow [Michał Niklas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22595/michal-niklas)'s suggestion [from his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482693/error-inserting-entry-with-text-column-that-contains-new-line-and-quotes#comment13564329_10483762), and use `PreparedStatement`. This could potentially be explained by Informix handing the `TEXT` data type in its own manner.

Answer (score 3):

Informix's TEXT (and BYTE) columns pre-date any standard, and are in many ways very peculiar types.  TEXT in Informix is very different from TEXT found in other DBMS.  One of the long-standing (over 20 years) problems with them is that there isn't a string literal notation that can be used to insert data into them.  The 'No cast from char to text' is saying there is no explicit conversion from string literal to TEXT, either.

You have a variety of options:

- Use LVARCHAR in the table (good if your values won't be longer than a few KiB, because the total row length is approximately 32 KiB).  Maximum size of an LVARCHAR column is just under 32 KiB.
- Use a programming language which can handle Informix 'locator' structures — in ESQL/C, the type used to hold a TEXT is `loc_t`.
- Consider using CLOB instead.  However, this has the same limitation (no string to CLOB conversion), but you'd be able to use the `FILETOCLOB()` function to get the information from a file on the client to the database (and `LOTOFILE` transfers information from the DB to a file on the client).

If you can use LVARCHAR, that is by far the simplest alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, it is Java that is used to communicate with the database, and an ORM (Hibernate in particular). Therefore I fear I cannot take advantage of the `loc_t` locator structure. As for the LVARCHAR type, it looks like it has approximately the same limitations as the NVARCHAR for the MS SQL Server, or am I wrong? If not, I fear that our text columns would hold longer strings than 4096 characters (if UTF-8 is used).

Comment: LVARCHAR defaults to 2048 bytes, but can go up to a shade short of 32 KiB.  But the whole row length also has the 32 KiB limit.  BYTE, TEXT, BLOB and CLOB store a fixed size (56-byte or 64-byte) descriptor in the row and the data is stored elsewhere.  LVARCHAR is stored in the row.  How big do you need to get?  Which JDBC driver are you using? The Informix driver (as opposed to Java Common Client or JCC version of JDBC) should handle BYTE, TEXT reasonably well, but probably not as a string literal as in the SQL shown.

Comment: I assume you tried without the CAST and it failed?  People don't normally go adding CAST until they've run into a problem, but just in case...

Comment: We are using the IBM's Informix Driver. Most of the data stored is large CSV data, being read from files uploaded by users. The application has already been written to use PostgreSQL, therefore no direct reading of files from the DB server is done. Our task is to migrate the same application to use Informix. And, yes, I have tried using `CAST` unsuccessfully.

Comment: You can also try to use PreparedStatement. It works well with JDBC and TEXT columns. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483284/consistent-method-of-inserting-text-column-to-informix-database-using-jdbc-and-o

Comment: @MichałNiklas, thanks, the prepared statement was the way I resolved the issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, since I actually discovered the answer in a comment, I'd attempt to give it credit by creating a community-wiki answer. I just recently discovered that [this is a preferred approach](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments/251598#251598) in such situations, discussed in meta. Please, do not feel offended in any way as I am about to un-mark this as an answer, the post is still useful and informative. Besides, the comment would not have been there if not for your answer :)